# Well-ordering the set of all finite sequences.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(A,<)$ be well-ordered set, using <, how can one define well-order on set of finite sequences?

(I thought using lexicographic order)

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem with the lexicographic order?

Comment: Haim told me to say hi. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, now his question are famous! :)

Comment: I would have written better questions! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lexicographic order is fine, but you need to make a point where one sequence extends another -- there the definition of the lexicographic order may break down. In this case you may want to require that the shorter sequence comes before the longer sequence.

Generally speaking, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two well-ordered sets, then we know how to well-order $\alpha\times\beta$ (lexicographically, or otherwise). We can define by recursion a well-order of $\alpha^n$ for all $n$, and then define the well-order on $\alpha^{<\omega}$ as comparison of length, and if the two sequences have the same length, $n$, then we can compare them by the well-order of $\alpha^n$.